# form jumpin on iphone mobile view

Tags: php, iphone, wordpress, forms, responsive

I have a form using a form 7 plugin in wordress under a Divi theme, it is working fine on android phone view but I have issue on iphone view.

On iphone view, when typing on a textfield it jumps to the next textfield without finishing the input. does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: That's not normal behavior, so we're going to have to see either some code or an example for us to see the behavior in action.

Comment: the form is on the http://grandislandchiropractic.com/ "Ask Questions"

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with PHP?  This is likely more of an HTML/CSS/Javascript issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is the carousel. As it rotates, the content *within* it is of different heights, making the form move around in the page. It's not just happening to the form - go to the "Welcome to Notaro Chiropractic Offices" heading and wait a little while. You'll see it jump all around the page.